While creating a release build in Android Studio, I am getting the error 'Unresolved reference: GsonConverterFactory'. How can I resolve this issue?
While creating a release build in Android Studio, I am getting the error 'Unresolved reference: GsonConverterFactory' or Gson. How can I resolve this issue?
Use Case:

I can run the app successfully
I can Take generated signed debug build
Not Able to take generated signed release build its shows an above error.

Libraries files i added:
[versions]
retrofit = "2.9.0"
okhttp = "4.12.0"
googleGson = "2.10.1"

[libraries]
retrofit = { module = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit", version.ref = "retrofit" }
retrofit-gson = { module = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson", version.ref = "retrofit" }
google-gson = { module = "com.google.code.gson:gson", version.ref = "googleGson" }
okhttp-logging = { module = "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor", version.ref = "okhttp" }


Please include the relevant parts of the log where this error is logged. Just the error message without context makes it difficult to understand what is going wrong.

Do you have a proguard file?

Yes, I added keep annotations each data class.
